# How to set home page in orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard cms but set to home page check box is not visibe please anybody tell how to set my content page as home page.whether i want to add content types in page.please do this helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't have the permission to set the home page.

As a side note, please try not to cross-post, and ask your questions either on Codeplex or here. You will get an answer either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the common part or the routable part to your contentType.